What is the difference of TypeScript vs TypeScript + SWC when creating a Vite project?
I'm working on a project using Vite, and I want to understand the difference between using TypeScript alone and TypeScript with SWC. I've searched online but couldn't find a clear explanation. I believe it would be helpful to get answers from experienced developers, which is why I'm asking here. Could someone explain the differences and when it's better to use one over the other?


The + SWC options use SWC for transpilation instead of Babel, which is generally faster than the non-SWC option, but might (in rare cases) have bugs. (For React, this really means whether to choose this or this Vite plugin.)
I would select a + SWC option.

The Vite projects using Typescript option use Babel, and using Typescript + SWC option use SWC.
SWC
Advantages:

Performance: Faster than Babel, ideal for short build times.
Written in Rust: Leverages efficiency and concurrency.
Simplicity: Requires less initial configuration.

Disadvantages:

Limited Ecosystem: Fewer plugins and preset availables, at moment.
Compatibility: Some features may not be fully implemented yet.
Less Maturity: Smaller community (growing) and documentation compared to Babel.

Project Types:

New projects prioritizing speed.
Medium to large applications.
Situations where simplicity is key.

Babel
Advantages:

Robust Ecosystem: A fast array of plugins and presets.
Customization: Detailed configuration for specific needs.
Maturity and Support: Extensive documentation and active community.

Disadvantages:

Performance: Generally slower compared to SWC.
Complex Configuration: Can be complicated for less experienced developers.

Project Types:

Large and complex projects requiring custom transformations.
Applucations relying on various libraries and tools.
Situtations where compatibility with the latest javascript features is critical.


A resume of differences between Babel and SWC according to my point of view and what I understood.
Sources:

https://swc.rs/docs/getting-started
https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-react-swc?tab=readme-ov-file
https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-react/tree/main/packages/plugin-react


SWC is a compiler/transpiler and bundler for Javascript/Typescript, generally it's faster than other options like babel, tsc, esbuild. SWC website: SWC
